# Fatal error: Call to undefined function mb_convert_encoding() in /home/shaadistore/public_html/lib/Pelago/Emogrifier.php on line 556

Tags: magento-1.9, email

my site is http://shaadistore.in/ in this im having an issue in forgot password page http://shaadistore.in/customer/account/forgotpassword/  whenever i'm submitting the form it's showing below error:

Fatal error: Call to undefined function mb_convert_encoding() in /home/shaadistore/public_html/lib/Pelago/Emogrifier.php on line 556

And also i'm not getting any emails during this process.

Please can any body help me about this.

Comment: i tried no error on that link

Answer (score 7):

It looks like your PHP installation doesn't have `mbstring` installed.

Go through this guide, it will give you more information on how to install it:
http://php.net/manual/en/mbstring.installation.php

If you don't have that much access on your server, contact your hosting provider and ask them to do it for you